# facing floating left and right issues

Tags: html

I need 2 divs inside a big one:
the first will float left and second will float right
i gave the 1st div width of 75% and the 2nd 25%, it seems that the 2nd div is not finding its right place so it keeps coming under the left div on the right side

this is my code:

```
<div class="centerDiv2">
        <span class="title2">LATEST BULLETIN</span>
        <hr>
        <div class="divLeft">
            <img src="images/5891.jpg"/>
            <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
            <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
        </div>

        <div class="divLeft">
            <img src="images/42St.jpg"/>
            <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
            <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
        </div>

        <div class="divRight">
            <span class="title">RECENTLY</span>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.divLeft {
    width:70%;
    margin: 30 0;
}

.title2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family: courier;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.centerDiv2 {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 30 auto;
}

.divRight {
    width:25%;
    height:400px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    float:right;
    margin: 30 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="centerDiv2">
    <span class="title2">LATEST BULLETIN</span>
    <hr>
<div class="leftDiv">
    <div class="divLeft">
        <img src="images/5891.jpg"/>
        <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
        <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
    </div>

    <div class="divLeft">
        <img src="images/42St.jpg"/>
        <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
        <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="divRight">
        <span class="title">RECENTLY</span>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title2 {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight:bolder;
   font-family: courier;
   width: 100%;
}
.leftDiv{
   width: 70%; display: inline-block;
}
.divRight { 
   display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height: 400px; width: 25%;background-color: lightgray;
 }
```

Comment: better code than mine but im still getting the right div under the left one

Comment: okay it works perfectly thanks. Just one more questions, do i always need to set the height of a div? because i didn't and i get the next div in front of it instead of under. there is no other way than specifying the height?

Comment: **left div with 70 %**

Answer (score 0):

hi dude the issue is with width 75% and 25% using with the margin because you are giving margin though you have already 100% of you canvas means(body)

```css
.wrapper{
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.divLeft {
    width:70%;    
    background-color:red;
}

.title2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-family: courier;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.centerDiv2 {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.divRight {
    width:25%;
    height:400px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    float:right;
    margin: 30px 0;
      background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerDiv2">
        <span class="title2">LATEST BULLETIN</span>
        <hr>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="divLeft">
            <img src="images/5891.jpg"/>
            <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
            <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
        </div>

        <div class="divLeft">
            <img src="images/42St.jpg"/>
            <span class="title">JUL 19</span>
            <p class ="prog">"I Mathew</p>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="divRight">
            <span class="title">RECENTLY</span>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```